# Is the Omega 13 device single use?

Tags: galaxy-quest

In Galaxy Quest, we know the Omega 13 device can

> go back in time by 13 seconds

Which allows the person who activated it to redeem a single mistake.

Can the device be used multiple times? If the attempt to fix a mistake fails, can you activate it again to try again?

Because

> once activated, everything resets back 13 seconds. This includes the device itself which is reset back to its normal non activated state

Comment: Personally, the device would be useless to me.  My mistakes always take much longer than 13 seconds to fix!

Comment: But _not_ everything resets back 13 seconds, otherwise it would be pointless because the same things would occur.  Information goes back, and that information can include the state of the device.

Comment: @DavidW but thats not true.  Only the person who triggers it remembers what happened.  Thats the only information that flows back.  Everything else has no knowledge of what happened in those 13 seconds.

Comment: If that can persist through the time rewind, why can't the state of the device?